# Automatically alter/reset jQuery's position().left depending on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, warnings

I am making a menu for my new website and it initially has the following CSS:

```
margin: 20px 20px 0;
```

`f-nav` class:

```
.f-nav {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;

    margin: 0 !important; /* <------------ Problem */

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out !important;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out !important;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out !important;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out !important;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out !important;
}
```

So this is the code I use to make my menu fixed on top of the page, by giving it the class `.f-nav`. This also accounts for my fancy menu line which moves on mouse hover, over the menu items:

```
window.onload = function () {
    "use strict";
    var menu = $("#menu");
    menu.append("<div id=\"menu-line\"></div>");

    var foundActive = false;
    var activeElement;
    var linePosition = 0;
    var menuLine = $("#menu #menu-line");
    var lineWidth;
    var defaultPosition;
    var defaultWidth;

    $("#menu > ul > li").each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
            activeElement = $(this);
            foundActive = true;
        }
    });

    if (foundActive === false) {
        activeElement = $("#menu > ul > li").first();
    }

    defaultWidth = lineWidth = activeElement.width();

    defaultPosition = linePosition = activeElement.position().left;

    menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
    menuLine.css("left", defaultPosition);

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 62) {
            menu.addClass("f-nav");
            menuLine.css("left", defaultPosition + 20); // <------- Warning
        } else {
            menu.removeClass("f-nav");
            menuLine.css("left", defaultPosition); // <------- Warning
        }
    });

    $("#menu > ul > li").hover(function () {
        activeElement = $(this);
        lineWidth = activeElement.width();
        linePosition = activeElement.position().left;
        menuLine.css("width", lineWidth);
        menuLine.css("left", linePosition);
    }, function () {
        if (menu.hasClass("f-nav")) {
            menuLine.css("left", defaultPosition + 20);
        } else {
            menuLine.css("left", defaultPosition);
        }
        menuLine.css("width", defaultWidth);
    });

};
```

The above code works as intended. It properly changes the line's position according to the margin. But in Firefox console I get the following warning:

> This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!

Is there any way to work around this warning? I just want to have my menu line at the correct position when the `#menu` margin changes, but I've been stuck with this error all day :/

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**
JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/41yu09t4/

Comment: Can you post an url where your code has been deployed like github or codepen or something like that

Comment: Any suggestions? I know the way I am doing it now is wrong because of the error, so can somebody guide me in the right direction on how to properly calculate line position, to get the expected behavior?

Comment: Is it an error or a warning?if it is a warning we usually don't have to bother about it unless it is mandatory that there should be no warnings as well

Comment: Well I'm trying to work my way around the warning (and the weird behavior) with CSS3 and `a:hover:before` and honestly it's beginning to work. The movement animation may not be that smooth but if it doesn't give me problems like the ones I've described above, I'd go with it any day of the week.